# Matlab corrplot function stopped working

Tags: matlab, correlation

The weirdest thing happened, it seems as Matlab corrplot function just stopped working. I have a piece of code which always worked perfectly fine. Now the same code is throwing an error. When I try

```
corrplot(CE,'varNames',{'Diam.','Depth','Rad.','Thick','Thin'})
```

I get:

> Undefined function 'corrplot' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: Did you accidentally define a new function also called `corrplot`? what does `which corrplot` output? Does this problem persist on a fresh instance of MATLAB where aside from manually assigning data to `CE`, that is the only line of code you run?

Answer (score 1):

The function is [not deprecated](http://mathworks.com/help/econ/corrplot.html), meaning that probably your Econometrics Toolbox is no longer available. You can check for the available toolboxes in your MATLAB license by running `ver`. Additionally you should run

```
which corrplot
C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Production Server\R2015a\toolbox\econ\econ\corrplot.m
```

To show you whether it is around somewhere. I reckon something went wrong with the toolbox installation, so you should check whether you still have a valid license and, if so, reinstal the toolbox.

You might also have a variable called `corrplot` (`which corrplot` tells you whether that is the case) although in my case the error then is:

```
CE = [1:10].';
corrplot=1;
corrplot(CE,'varNames',{'Diam.','Depth','Rad.','Thick','Thin'})
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.

which corrplot
corrplot is a variable. % Not good, you didn't want that.
```

Clear the variable with `clear corrplot` and check where in your code it creates this variable and rename it.